# How to use an aggregate function in linq

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, aggregate

I want to get the average of this query.

```
From d In (From c In location.Descendants("temperature") Where c.Attribute("type").Value = "hourly" Select c).Descendants("value")
                 Take 3
                Select d
```

I can see the aggregate keyword in the autocomplete dropdown, but I cant figure out how to apply it. Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 4):

@Muzz above notes the Average() extension method, but Aggregate is a useful function too:

For a nice example of the `Aggregate` function in action, try [here](http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=509fa3f8-c125-4e61-9227-8ca4c4e29210) . So you could try something like the following:

```
myList = location.Descendants("temperature")
             .Where(c => c.Attribute("type").value == "hourly")
             .Select(...)

average = myList.Aggregate( (i1, i2) => i1+i2) / myList.Length
```

Excuse my conversion to lambda-syntax, and I've left out the bit where you actually get the integer value you need. The .Aggregate function is a bit like `fold_left` from a functional language:

```
(new [] {1, 2, 3, 4}).Aggregate( (i1, i2) => i1+i2)
```

is like writing:

```
((1 + 2) + 3) + 4
```

To use the example from the link, you could implement a comma-separated list by doing:

```
IQueryable<String> ListOfStrings = ...
ListOfStrings.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " s2)
```

By combining Linq expressions like `Aggregate` with C#'s particularly succinct lambda expressions, you can write really expressive, yet very powerful code. If you've any experience with a functional language, you can think of these LINQ constructs in those terms.

Comment: When possible you should post code examples in the same language that the OP is using.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the average extension method. (expression).Average()

e.g.

```
(From d In (From c In location.Descendants("temperature") Where c.Attribute("type").Value =    "hourly" Select c).Descendants("value")
             Skip GetTimeOffset() Take 1
            Select d).Average()
```